# How make SOAP Request Cross-domain with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know how make a SOAP Request that support cross-domain with JQuery.
I searched for it, but I did find a clearly example about how do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this, only [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) is allowed cross-domain.  You'll have to proxy the request through your own domain if you want a SOAP request.

To be a little clearer on this, the only way JSONP gets around this is the restrictions on what you can do, it creates a `<script>` tag that goes a GET to fetch your data, and runs a JavaScript function already defined in the page.